# form validation: check that multiple checbox and radio buttons are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a form that has a lot of conditional paths.. for instance..

- Q1.a -> triggers the appearance of question 3
- Q1.b -> triggers the appearance of question 2
- Q1.c -> skips all the way to question 16

All the questions are required if they're visible to the form user. This being the case I can't just put `required` in the inputs in case it's one that doesn't get shown.

I've been applying my "required" class in this fashion

```
    $('.question2-a').click(function() {
        $(".question3").toggle();           
        $(".question3").addClass("required"); 
        $(".question4").toggle();             
        $(".question4").addClass("required");
        $(".question5").toggle();             
        $(".question5").addClass("required");             
   });

   $('.question2-b').click(function() {       
        $(".question5").toggle();             
        $(".question5").addClass("required");             
    });
```

In this way only questions that I know appeared get a class of required.

I now need to do a look-up of all the required inputs that appeared and ensure they were properly selected.

So far I have this...

```
$('#PWLE').submit(function() {
   if ($('.required input:checkbox', this).is(':checked') && $('.required input:radio', this).is(':checked')) {
     // everything's fine...
   } 
   else {
     alert('Please fill out all required fields');
     return false;
   }
});
```

This isn't really doing the trick because as soon as one checkbox and radio are selected the `if` is satisfied and the form will submit.

Is there a way I can loop through my `required` class to ensure that `if` statement logic is running on all of them?

**Snippet of HTML Form**

```
<!-- Question #2 -->
<div class="form-group question2">
    <p><b><span class="req-notice">*</span>Have you received a newsletter in the past two years?</b></p>
    <div class="form-check question2-a">            
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="Yes" id="2261_9466_4_42752_1" name="2261_9466_4_42752">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="2261_9466_4_42752_1">
        Yes
        </label>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-check question2-b">            
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="No" id="2261_9466_4_42752_2" name="2261_9466_4_42752">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="2261_9466_4_42752_2">
        No
        </label>
    </div>            
</div>
<!-- End of Question #2 -->


 <!-- Question #3  -->
<div class="form-group question3">
    <p><b><span class="req-notice">*</span>When did you register for the  newsletter? (choose only ONE)</b></p>
    <div class="form-check">            
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="In the past 6 months" id="2261_9466_5_42753_1" name="2261_9466_5_42753">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="2261_9466_5_42753_1">
        In the past 6 months
       </label>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-check">            
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="Between 6 to 12 months" id="2261_9466_5_42753_2" name="2261_9466_5_42753">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="2261_9466_5_42753_2">
        Between 6 to 12 months
       </label>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-check">            
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="Between 1 to 2 years" id="2261_9466_5_42753_3" name="2261_9466_5_42753">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="2261_9466_5_42753_3">
        Between 1 to 2 years
        </label>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-check">            
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="More than 2 years" id="2261_9466_5_42753_4" name="2261_9466_5_42753">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="2261_9466_5_42753_4">
        More than 2 years
        </label>
    </div>         
</div>
<!-- End of Question #3 -->
```

Comment: try using my `js-formation` form validation package, that has built in support for checkboxes and gives a mechanism for dealing with related fields. https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-formation

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML as well, so we can reproduce the problem you're describing?

Comment: Could you post the html part or screenshot for the same, it will be easier for people if they visualize/see the problem.

Comment: @vS12 please see edit

Comment: @DavidThomas please see edit

Comment: @vS12: if you meant that the OP - I'm not typing out that full name - could post a picture of his HTML? No. No, he cannot. That's less than useless.

Comment: HTML snippet included now.

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 So, all required fields have "required" class ? Are you to do this ?

Comment: @DavidThomas : I just wanted to get an idea of how the UI looked like, because it was difficult to visualize the UI and placement of elements from his question.

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 why don't you set a default value for these radio buttons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".q1.required").click(function(){
      if(this.value == "yes"){
        $("#div3").show();
        $("#div3 :input").prop('required',true);
      }
      else{
        $("#div3").hide();
        $("#div3 :input").prop('required',false);
      }
  });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="">
    <div id="div1">
    <label><b>Question 1</b></label>
    <input  name="q1" class = "q1 required" type="radio" value = "yes" required>
    <input  name="q1" class = "q1 required" type="radio" value = "no" required>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <label><b>Question 2</b></label>
    <input id="q2" name="q2" class = "required" type="radio" value = "no" required>
    <input id="q2" name="q2" class = "required" type="radio" value = "yes" required>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id = "div3" style="display:none;">
    <label><b>Question 3</b></label>
    <input id="q3" name="q3" class = "" type="radio" value = "yes">
    <input id="q3" name="q3" class = "" type="radio" value = "no">
    <br>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

- You can use `required` attribute instead of class for enabling automatic validation on click of submit/button.
- Keep class "required" just for triggering the click event.

Refer the code above :

1. I have displayed 2 questions,and on click of "yes" of first question I display third question and set the input attribute as `required` and then if you click "no" then I hide the question and remove the 'required' attribute.

This code is a working example, feel free to run it and check.

Comment: Thanks! I was over-complicating it, toggling the required attribute makes much more sense.